# GET request from ember data to simple express resource hangs in 'pending' state forever

Tags: ember.js, express, ember-data

I'm having trouble with Ember data `App.store.findAll` requests to a GET method handle I've set up in Express. Here's the code I'm using:

server:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/transactions', function(req, res) {
    console.log('request received');
    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.send([{'foo':'bar'}]);
});

app.listen(8891);
```

client:

```
var App = Em.Application.create();
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 4,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        bulkCommit: false
    })
});

App.Transaction = DS.Model.extend({
    foo: DS.attr('string')
});

App.transactionsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    init: function() {
        this.set('content', App.store.findAll(App.Transaction));
    }
});

App.TransactionsView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'transactions'
});
```

I can curl the /transactions route without issue, but the data is not coming across to Ember. Looking at the requests issued on page-load in Chrome, I see a request to '/transactions', but this request stays in 'pending' state forever. The 'request received' logging step I added is not getting invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not a cross origin request issue? (you'd see an error in the logs)

Comment: @pauldechov not that I'm aware of. Ember's request are issued from the page back to its origin. There are no errors in the console.